# What is a decode_slice_header error? Can this error output be solved?

Tags: ffmpeg

While trying to decode or even get any useful information about .mts file, using in this case this command:

```
ffmpeg -i URL
```

I am always getting these errors:

```
[h264 @ 0xb4c080] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 0xb4c080] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0xb4c080] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 0xb4c080] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0xb4c080] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xb4c080] no frame!
```

Is there a way to fix it? The program after all these errors continues processing but the output doesn't work. Is there a problem with the file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, The problem is in the file. It starts with a non key frame. Once the first key frame is encountered, the decoder can do its job. If the output is good enough, ignore the error.  If it’s not, source the original file.

Comment: In fact, trying to decode in another computer the problem was still appearing but having a correct output nonetheless.