# Bad files generated by GStreamer mpegtsmux and multifilesink

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtsp

I'm pretty new to GStreamer, and I'm trying to make a simple pipeline to save the RTSP stream from a network camera to a series of .ts files. The camera streams H.264 video. The pipeline looks like this:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="$camera_url" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! multifilesink location="file-%05d.ts" aggregate-gops=true max-file-duration=1200000000000 next-file=5
```

This works pretty well, and I get playable .ts files as expected. However, on *some* of the files when I try to remux them or process them in any way with ffmpeg I get errors like the following:

```
[h264 @ 0x7f7f4ca3b880] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x7f7f4ca3b880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f7f4ca3b880] no frame!
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347225/931860) I get the impression that GStreamer is generating files that don't start with a keyframe. Although, that's exactly what I thought the `aggregate-gops=true` parameter is supposed to fix. So, two questions:

1. Any ideas on how to fix my pipeline to get good files out of it every time?
2. Is there a tool I can use to inspect the generated .ts files to see if they actually do start with a keyframe (maybe there is another problem causing these errors)?

Comment: Hi! We are also running into a similar issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Sadly, no. I wound up abandoning GStreamer because of this and switching to ffmpeg. It has been much more stable for my use case.

Comment: We noticed that removing `h264parse` from the pipeline actually fixed issues i.e. key frame as the first frame of every segment with: `ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time,flags -of csv=print_section=0 video00.ts | less`. I think the only difference is that I used `splitmuxsink`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If I ever have to revisit GStreamer, I will definitely give that a shot.